# WiFi doorbell cams (on or off topic?)

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Simple question. Would we consider WiFi doorbell cameras, and questions relating to how they connect wirelessly to be on-topic?

Comment: I would consider them off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if the problem is in connecting them to a computer, using standard software provided for them to do so.

If the problem is in using them with a smartphone application then for Android phones or tablets you may be able to ask at [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com) or for iOS devices there is [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com). For using the webapp there would be [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com).

Otherwise on its own the camera would probably [be off-topic as an](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

> electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer

Comment: There is also [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks guys, I was given three doorbell cams. The hypothetical question was more **if** it was possible to connect via PC software. They are clearly Chinese clones of more popularly branded cameras, and about zero documentation for them online from the manufacturers. Without the ability to connect them via VLC stream or OpenSource DVR software, I would consider them trash.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart If there's an FCC ID on them, you might be able to identify a chipset and/or communication mechanism from that ID by using fcc.io or some such service

Comment: @QuickishFM, awesome idea. Unfortunately they don't have a FCC, UL, or even a CE marking/sticker. These seem to be some of the devices from Amazon that are circumventing our safety/communication standards coming from china. I'll pop one open before I toss em and see if they have a esp32 or something reprogrammable to tinker with. Thanks for the suggestion!